# Add Package-scope Variable to Output (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm trying  to create an SSIS package to move data from an Excel spreadsheet into a SQL Server 2005 table. It's mostly going okay, considering that this is the third time I've tried to build a package at all (not what you'd call a flat learning curve).

The one thing I'm just not getting through my skull is how to include a package-scoped variable as an output column--that is, to insert it into the table, on every row, along with the data that's pulled in from the Excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a derived column transformation in the data flow, and then in the formula expression of the derived column, add in the variable (it should be in the tree list of available variables)